# CRUD and FLS checks for Batch class , Are they mandatory from security review prospective?

Tags: apex, batch, security-review

I am working on product and we have lot of Apex Batch Classes developed, I submitted my org code for Checkmarx review and I got lot of security review changes regarding CRUD and FLS check.

However I am wondering about Apex Batch, do CRUD checks and FLS checks are required for batch class as they are running in system mode?

Please advise.

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: Great. I posted as an answer so you can close out the question if you wish

Comment: @Eric Thank you so much for prompt reply, yeah I was about to say you to post these comments into answer so that I can accept the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can state the reason for the "system mode" and it is valid then you submit those reasons when you submit the app for review. The scanner is a tool not the decision maker. The security team will be checking to ensure that the code you have running in "system mode" should be doing so and allow it if appropriate

Batch class is no different that any other class in that regard. "With Sharing" respects sharing, "Without Sharing" does not. As for FLS all code has access to ALL fields. That is why you are supposed to explicitly check and handle it within your code